# PHP shell_exec() won't give same results as bash

Tags: php, linux, bash, system-administration

ISSUE: Echo from bash file isn't recognized PHP. The echo is the file name and is sent back to the webserver to make the redirect.

It works like this:

PHP file on website is accessed and runs this code:

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec("sshpass -p [serverpass] ssh root@[serverip] 'sh         
 /var/www/[bashfile].sh'");

$vpn="http://[serverip]/".$output.".ovpn";
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $vpn));
header('Location: '.$string);
?>
```

When I run

```
sshpass -p [serverpass] ssh root@[serverip] 'sh /var/www/auto.sh'
```

in bash on the webserver, it runs the echo. However, when executed with `php [filename].php` it doesn't.

Here is the bash code on the server w/ bash (not webserver):

```
#!/bin/sh

newclient () {
    if [ -e /home/$1 ]; then
            homeDir="/home/$1"
    elif [ ${SUDO_USER} ]; then
            homeDir="/home/${SUDO_USER}"
    else
            homeDir="/root"
    fi
    cp /etc/openvpn/client-template.txt $homeDir/$1.ovpn
    echo "<ca>" >> $homeDir/$1.ovpn
    cat /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt >> $homeDir/$1.ovpn
    echo "</ca>" >> $homeDir/$1.ovpn
    echo "<cert>" >> $homeDir/$1.ovpn
    cat /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/$1.crt >> $homeDir/$1.ovpn
    echo "</cert>" >> $homeDir/$1.ovpn
    echo "<key>" >> $homeDir/$1.ovpn
    cat /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/$1.key >> $homeDir/$1.ovpn
    echo "</key>" >> $homeDir/$1.ovpn
    echo "key-direction 1" >> $homeDir/$1.ovpn
    echo "<tls-auth>" >> $homeDir/$1.ovpn
    cat /etc/openvpn/tls-auth.key >> $homeDir/$1.ovpn
    echo "</tls-auth>" >> $homeDir/$1.ovpn
}

                    var=`date +%s%N`
                    cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/
                    ./easyrsa build-client-full $var nopass
                    newclient "$var"
                    mv ~/$var.ovpn /var/www/$var.ovpn
                    echo "$var"
exit
;;
```

Comment: Can you echo the $output value?

Comment: Just a minor thing: if that `shell_exec` ever fails and gives off a fatal error, your error message may be displaying the root password of a server that actually allows ssh connections by the root user. You might want to consider an alternative approach to this.

Comment: @Mohit Kumar Nice catch.  It turns out I can, and even echo the $string value. It starts having problems at the redirect.

Comment: @rickdenhaan That is true. I'll add `error_reporting(0);` to the top of the PHP files when it's in production. z